# Chrome extension injecting css only on classes with specific content

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know how to inject CSS into a webpage, and change a certain class, but what if I don't want to change all of that class?

For example, say I have a div:

```
<div class="content">
   <p> My favorite color is yellow </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
   <p> My favorite color is green </p>
</div>
```

I want to use content scripts to edit the CSS of the `.content` class, but only ones that contain the keyword, `"green"`

Would I have to use Javascript, if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to using jQuery you could use the [:contains() selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

**Example**

```js
$(".content:contains('green')").css("color", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>My favorite color is yellow</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>My favorite color is green</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or make it very simple like below

```
var item = $('.content');
  for (var i = 0; i <= item.length; i++) {
   if ($(item[i]).text().indexOf("green")>= 0) {
         $(item[i]).css('color','red');
      }
  }
```